# Why will this not run?

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
answr = input(" Convert to celsius or fahrenheit?")
if answr == "fahrenheit":
    print ( "fahrenheit" )
else:
    print ('celsius')
celsius = int(input("Temperature =")) 
fahrenheit = int(input("Temperature =")
fahr = float(input("fahrenheit" * 1.8 + 32))
cels = int(input('celsius' - 32) * 1.8)
```

I keep getting errors please tell me what im doing wrong and explain to me, as im still very new at this and trying to learn.

Comment: Please, tell us what is this error you are getting?

Comment: u forgot a ' ) ' on the 7th line

Comment: Missing close paren on this line `fahrenheit = int(input("Temperature =")`. Should be `fahrenheit = int(input("Temperature ="))`

Comment: also you're using input instead of raw_input, so user has to write "celsius" instead of celsius, with the ' "" 's

Comment: The error im getting is: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @EmilianoSorbello python 3 doesn't have raw_input.

Comment: First it asks me for the temperature twice then it gives me the TypeError                  @NightShadeQueen

Comment: `input("fahrenheit" * 1.8 + 32)`, you shouldn't give a expression in input().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there're many errors i should just compile (heh) them into one answer:

1. 7th line needs another right parenthesis
2. doing this: `"fahrenheit" *1.8 + 32` breaks horribly because you are trying to multiply a string with a float. Also adding strings to ints is a no-go.
3. Even if we fix these syntax errors, your code's probably not going to do what you want it to do.

You may need something like this:

```
answr = input(" Convert to celsius or fahrenheit?")
temp = int(input("Temperature ="))
if answr == "fahrenheit":
    print (temp * 1.8 + 32)
else:
    print ((temp  - 32) * 1.8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Emiliano, you are a great help.